# Ability to reset IEnumerator generated using yield (C#)

Tags: c#

If I use yield instead of manually creating an IEnumerator, is it possible to implement IEnumerator.Reset?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you would expect this "reset" to do? What happens to a caller who is half way through a "foreach" statement, iterating over your results?

Comment: @Matt: I want to implement the standard enumerator reset method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset.aspx

Comment: Yeah, but IEnumerator.Reset doesn't really gel with "yield return". You're supplying values to an enumerator that's in progress - it doesn't make sense to reset it from your end. The calling code is respondible for resetting.

Comment: @Matt: I know the calling code should reset it. Hence why I want to implement the method!

Comment: IEnumerator.Reset is not implemented by most .NET enumerators: the CLR docs explicitly state, "The Reset method is provided for COM interoperability. It does not necessarily need to be implemented; instead, the implementer can simply throw a NotSupportedException."  So unless you're talking to COM code it's probably not worth bothering.  Could you say more about your use case?

Comment: I just thought it'd be good practice to implement it if it wasn't too hard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no built-in support, but you can define your own implementation of `IEnumerator` that delegates all method calls to the enumerator generated by C# and only lets you define your own behavior for the `Reset` method.

The simplest version of the class would look like this:

```
class ResetableEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
  public IEnumerator<T> Enumerator { get; set; }
  public Func<IEnumerator<T>> ResetFunc { get; set; }

  public T Current { get { return Enumerator.Current; } }
  public void  Dispose() { Enumerator.Dispose(); }
  object IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }
  public bool  MoveNext() { return Enumerator.MoveNext(); }
  public void  Reset() { Enumerator = ResetFunc(); }
}
```

In this case, the `ResetFunc` that you specify returns a new `IEnumerator<T>`, so your provided implementation of `ResetFunc` can do some cleanup or whatever you need to do when resetting and then return a new enumerator.

```
IEnumerator<int> Foo() { /* using yield return */ }
IEnumerator<int> PublicFoo() {
  return new ResetableEnumerator<int> { 
    Enumerator = Foo(),
    ResetFunc = () => { 
      Cleanup();
      return Foo(); } };
}
```

You'll need to store all the originally local variables of the `Foo` method as fields of the class, so that you can access them in `Cleanup` (Note that the rest of the `Foo` body will never be executed after calling `Reset`), but that's still easier than writing a handwritten iterator!

Answer (score 22):

No, it is not possible.  When the C# compiler processes an iterator (a method that contains a `yield` statement), the compiler generates a class that implements IEnumerable and IEnumerator.  The generated class' implementation of Reset just throws a NotSupportedException.  There is no way to influence this in current versions of C#.

Instead, your calling code will need to request a new enumerator, i.e. begin a new foreach loop.  Or you will need to forgo the language support (the `yield` statement) and write your own class which implements IEnumerator.

Comment: Note that your custom class implementing IEnumerator could internally use methods that "yield return".

Answer (score 7):

There's a nice workaround that I just discovered. Make your generator method return `IEnumerable`, **not** `IEnumerator`. Then you can do

```
var values = MyGeneratorMethod();
var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator();
// ... do stuff with enumerator
enumerator = values.GetEnumerator(); // instead of enumerator.Reset();
```

I believe itowlson's answer suggested this exact trick, but I couldn't understand it until I heard of the trick elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This code implements an attribute that can be set to reset the enumerator. Notes:

- Unfortunately,  this method of resetting won't work with multiple enumerators instances
- This doesn't reset it via the interface, but actually via setting a property either directly or through a method
- Given the complexity and the fragility, I actually wouldn't recommend this approach
- I'm actually wondering if a goto might be neater

Code:

```
public IEnumerator<Entry> GetEnumerator(){
    do{
        this.shouldReset=FALSE;
        for (Entry e = this.ReadEntry(); e != null; e = this.ReadEntry()){
            if(self.shouldReset)break;
            else yield return e;
        }
    }
    while(self.shouldReset)
}
```

Comment: @itowlson: Fixed the error. This doesn't actually implement the method, just provide a crudish work around with limitations. Unfortunately, my code isn't displaying properly anymore :-(

Comment: It looks like SO has a bug putting code blocks immediately after bullet lists.  I've kludged around it for you \*grin\*.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is to use a Wrapper class that can wrap any yielding function and reset:

```
public class Resettable : IEnumerator
{
  private IEnumerator inner;
  private Func<IEnumerator> func;

  public Resettable(Func<IEnumerator> func)
  {
    this.func = func;
    inner = func.Invoke();
  }

  public bool MoveNext()
  {
    return inner.MoveNext();
  }

  public object Current { get { return inner.Current; } }

  public void Reset()
  {
    inner = func.Invoke();
  }

  public static Resettable Make(Func<IEnumerator> func)
  {
    return new Resettable(func);
  }

  public static Resettable Make<T1>(Func<T1, IEnumerator> func, T1 a1)
  {
    Func<IEnumerator> capture = () => { return func.Invoke(a1); };
    return new Resettable(capture);
  }

  public static Resettable Make<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2, IEnumerator> func, T1 a1, T2 a2)
  {
    Func<IEnumerator> capture = () => { return func.Invoke(a1, a2); };
    return new Resettable(capture);
  }

  public static Resettable Make<T1, T2, T3>(Func<T1, T2, T3, IEnumerator> func, T1 a1, T2 a2, T3 a3)
  {
    Func<IEnumerator> capture = () => { return func.Invoke(a1, a2, a3); };
    return new Resettable(capture);
  }

  // add more of these to support more arguments
}
```

then, instead of calling your yielding method directly, you call `Resettable.Make(YourMethod, ..arguments..);`

so, here's an example usage:

```
public class Program
{ 
  static IEnumerator YieldTest(int start)
  {
    yield return start;
    yield return start + 1;
    yield return start + 2;
  }
    
  public static void Main()
  {
    // IEnumerator en = YieldTest(5);
    IEnumerator en = Resettable.Make(YieldTest, 5);

    while(en.MoveNext())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("value: "+en.Current.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Reset");
    en.Reset();
    while(en.MoveNext())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("value: "+en.Current.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
value: 5
value: 6
value: 7
Reset
value: 5
value: 6
value: 7
```